# Isolation forest package installation in R

Tags: r, gcc, machine-learning

I have used scikit-learn to implement Isolation forest and I need to implement it in R.

I found this implementation on github.
https://github.com/Zelazny7/isofor

when i tried to install it I got the following error

> 'make' not found for cmd.

I then installed gnuwin and added to environment variable and got around make.

Next I got an issue with compiling the code.
[image: Compilation error]

Seeing it was not able to detect compiler I followed the following example.
https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgsolve/issues/160

But I couldnt find gcc in my RBuildTools folder so I installed Mingw gcc compiler and added to path.
Now when when I try to fetch isofor from github I just keeps installing Rbuildtools again and again.

When i remove gcc from path I go back to previous error:127 in make.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the original version from R-forge built by Fei Tony Liu:

```
install.packages("IsolationForest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Also included, [the paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf) written by the people who came up with the model.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Just wanted to ask is it the same as isofor? @phiver

Comment: As far as I can see is that there is a difference in multicore support. Isofor can run multicore, the original isolation forest doesn't. Isofor has a c++ backend, isolation forest c. The underlying methods are the same.

Comment: I ran the Isolation forest for my analysis and got similar results to what I got with scikit-learn so will work for me. Thanks for the help. @phiver